# Android Spinner is not clickable or working while running app

Tags: android, eclipse, spinner, android-spinner

I am relatively new to programming and recently started working with android. I have been breaking my brains all day over this problem I have with a spinner. I read several similar questions and found several solutions and examples but none of them work for me :(

```
package com.deitel.welcome;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;



public class Preferences extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.preferences, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_profile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Preferences.this, Profile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.action_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Preferences.this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.action_calendar) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Preferences.this, CalendarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.action_statistics) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Preferences.this, Statistics.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private String[] states;
    private Spinner spinner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_list);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

And this is my customOnItemSelected java file:

```
package com.deitel.welcome;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
                "On Item Select : \n" +      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

}
```

This is my resources file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <string name="spinner_prompt">Choose a country</string>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>


</resources>
```

And this is of course my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/country_label"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/country_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone figure out what I did wrong?

Greetings! Rosa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! You are right... I found out that I actually created another class within my activity and did nothing in the original activity. Thanks for your help!

I kind of copied everything into the first class and added some stuff. Here is the code that worked for me in the end:

```
public class Preferences extends Activity { 

protected CharSequence[] _options = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
protected boolean[] _selections = new boolean[_options.length];

protected Button _optionsButton;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

    _optionsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    _optionsButton.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

}

public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showDialog(0);
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id) {

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Preferred Exercise Days")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(_options, _selections,
                    new DialogSelectionClickHandler())
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogButtonClickHandler())
            .create();
}
}

public class DialogSelectionClickHandler implements
        DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked,
            boolean selected) {
        Log.i("ME", _options[clicked] + " selected: " + selected);
    }
}

public class DialogButtonClickHandler implements
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
        switch (clicked) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            String selected = "";
            int i = 0;
            for (boolean b : _selections) {
                if (b) {
                    selected += _options[i] + " ;";
                }
                i++;
            }
            printSelectedDays();
            Toast.makeText(Preferences.this, "Selected: " + selected,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}



protected void printSelectedDays() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _options.length; i++) {
        Log.i("ME", _options[i] + " selected: " + _selections[i]);
    }
}
```

The solution is kind of different but it is actually what I wanted to achieve in the first place so I hope someone can use this after all.

Answer (score 0):

This fragment of your code:

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Adds listener without any logic because you didn;t provide any inside overriden methods. What you should do is add your custom listener like that:
`spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener())`

Answer (score 0):

you have done nothing in your on item selected . try adding a toast message in your main activity's on item selected and why is there a need for creating a custom listener when you can use the default one?

try like this in your main activity:

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"spinner clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

just try adding a toast in your default listener or else set the custom listener you have made.You are not setting it as your listener and hence nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `Spinner` Example and `Onclick listner`

```
 String[] tracks_time = { "3min", "5min", "10min" };

Spinner spinner_time = (Spinner)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.sp_time);
                ArrayAdapter<String> sptime = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, tracks_time);
                spinner_time.setAdapter(sptime);
  spinner_time.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position ,long arg3)
                {
                  int index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                  // get stuff as per index
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                {

                }
            });
```